# Fixed timestep periodical "lags"

Tags: java, android

I have fixed timestep code in my main thread, it looks like this:

```
float oldTimeSinceStart = 0;
float accumulatedTime = 0;
float maxDeltaTime = 0.1f; // 10 FPS
float fixedTime = 0.016f; // 60 FPS

while(running)
{
    float timeSinceStart = System.nanoTime();
    float deltaTime = (timeSinceStart - oldTimeSinceStart) / 1000000000;
    oldTimeSinceStart = timeSinceStart;

    deltaTime = Math.min(deltaTime, maxDeltaTime);

    accumulatedTime += deltaTime;

    while (accumulatedTime >= fixedTime)
    {
        accumulatedTime -= fixedTime;

        gamePanel.update();
    }

    gamePanel.draw(canvas);
}
```

I have objects on scene, which positions are updated as

```
position += speed;
```

And speed is calculated on app start as

```
speed = (screenWidth / 2) * fixedTime;
```

---

These codes should work well to get same objects speeds on all devices and also smooth visual. Speed works quite well, but visual appereance is bad. I'm getting periodical "lags" about each half second on my old Galaxy Ace and also on S III Mini. So it's like running smoothly - lag - running smoothly - lag...

Any ideas what could cause these lags?

Comment: My bet is on GC. Android is infamous for scheduling lenghty gc in the worst times - does System.gc(); after drawing help?

Comment: With that it does running periodical without the lag I've described, but with smaller lags (to compare it, it looks like when you running game on 10FPS so you see its lagging, but the game runs still on 10FPS - no drops). So, it's constant laggy movement.

Comment: Good, that is an improvement. Now try to create [less garbage](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html). Also, what(class of gamePanel) are you drawing onto? I know there are better(and worse) suited options.

Comment: So you mean I have to clear up and simplify code as much as possible right? Second question: sorry, I don't know what do you exactly mean. I'm calling draw(Canvas canvas) in gamepanel, and drawing physics and objects from there (doing player.draw(), walls.draw()...).

Comment: By the way, just small testing there: old Galaxy Ace S5830i and SIII Mini have these lags, but Galaxy S is running perfectly smooth (and thats strange, because newest is S3 mini...).

Comment: Read that linked official tips - if I am not mistaken tl;dr: dont `new` any objects that does not persist to next loop. You could also try running the GC periodically on another thread - in theory it could pause your main thread not for so long as if you executed it on the main thread. As for devices android is quite inconsistent in this, for example, my quite powerful phone ran at 20fps (probably lock I wasnt able to ever remove, no idea why) - on an old device it ran at 60fps smoothly.

Comment: I don't "new" more objects as necessary - I create them just until they come to screen and once they are out of it, I remove them. Also my game is quite a lot unassuming, there aren't many objects on scene.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32925/discussion-between-wondra-and-johnyx).